# Oracle developer. ORA-01722 Invalid Number when using UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have this problem:

I have two tables: Table A and Table B, with the same column called PK_COLUMN that in both tables are numeric(8, 0).

I want to make this union:

```
Select 
    CAST(TRIM(TABLEA.PK_COLUMN) AS INT) 
FROM TABLE A 
UNION 
Select 
    CAST(TRIM(TABLEB.PK_COLUMN) AS INT) 
FROM TABLE B
```

And I got the next error code:

> ORA-01722 Invalid number.

The problem is that when I execute the both parts of the union separately they work perfectly!

Comment: I don't think `numeric(8, 0)` is a thing. And, if you mean `number(8, 0)`, what sense does it make to trim spaces from it?

Comment: Sorry, number 8,0 . They have to be trim due to the numbers are for example 0 and I want to make the union, They work sepparate but not with the union

Comment: Are you aware that [TRIM()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) is a function to remove characters from texts? How can a number have white spaces?

Comment: One of the two tables must contain a value in pk_column which is not castable to INT. 
The reason why this works when calling the statements separately is, that your database IDE is limiting the result set by a given value. F.e. 50 records by default in SQL Developer (until you scroll down the result table) or 500 for Datagrip. 

The statement itself is working when providing an arbitrary set of numbers for the tables A and B. Can you execute select * from A where not regexp_like(pk_column, '[0-9]*') and the same for B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dominik Klug stated, one of the values in pk_column can not be converted to an INT. You are not getting an error when running the queries individually because you are not scanning all of the rows, just a subset of what is returned first. If you run queries like

```sql
Select DISTINCT CAST(TRIM(TABLEA.PK_COLUMN) AS INT) 
FROM TABLEA;

Select DISTINCT CAST(TRIM(TABLEA.PK_COLUMN) AS INT) 
FROM TABLEB;
```

you will be able to identify which table has problematic records.

If you are on Oracle 12.2 or higher, you can use the [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) function to identify which values are failing to convert to an INT with queries like the ones below.

```sql
Select *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(TABLEA.PK_COLUMN as NUMBER) = 0;

Select *
FROM TABLEB
WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(TABLEB.PK_COLUMN as NUMBER) = 0;
```